# Trouble installing django-heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, psycopg2

I am trying to deploy my django application to heroku.

When I try to `pip install django-heroku`, it gives me this error:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /Users/huntermackenzie/Dev/personal/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/
    Complete output (23 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing /private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to /private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/private/var/folders/15/k9lcjv5129v661mkkrsdt09w0000gn/T/pip-install-v2fvrgwp/psycopg2/pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

    Error: pg_config executable not found.

    pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory
    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the
    option:

        python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...

    or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.

    If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI
    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.

    For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at
    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Trying to `pip install psycopg2` gives me the same error.

Can someone please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please note that "backticks" are used to delimit blocks of code in Markdown, instead of the `'` marks you were using. I have fixed it for you, this time.

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests

```
pip install psycopg2-binary
```

have you tried it?

Comment: Yes I have but I still doesn't let me'''pip install django-heroku'''